# Reduce the impact of videos in memory to prevent crashes

Tags: codenameone

I have an app with potentially a very large amount of images and videos, depending on how many posts users make.

Already in development, with relatively few posts containing tabs with images and videos, occasionally the app crashes on real devices, I fear due to too much memory usage.

Are there any tips and strategies to optimize resource usage?

As for images, I only use medium-resolution regular EncodedImages (no multi-images), as backgrounds in Labels of fixed size.

As for videos, I only use short videos.

As for posts and videos (which are inside complex multilayer hierarchies with many Tabs), I use my own custom version of InfiniteContainer that, unlike the "default" version, never uses "removeAll" during a refresh, but just adds new posts, if any: this has already given me a great benefit in terms of performance. I also try to reuse the same instance of an InfiniteContainer full of images and videos, so I don't have to recreate every time the Media instances: also in this case there is a performance advantage, but everything remains loaded in memory.

Does the garbage collector do its job with videos?

It's not clear to me if Media.cleanup() does something or not with videos.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the Android memory profiler to try and track potential memory leaks and the source of such leaks. You can also use memory tracking on the simulator but that's a bit more challenging as some overhead stored in the "native system" would be hidden from Java based profilers.

`EncodedImage` is great for images that aren't shown. When they're shown they are "locked" and take up a lot of RAM. At that point they can't get GC'd. Make sure your infinite container unlocks components that are no longer a part of it. If you keep adding things to the infinite container you'll eventually run out of RAM. There's nothing you can do about that.

Images get "[locked](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/EncodedImage.html#unlock--)" when they're in use (e.g. in the current form but not necessarily visible). It's the responsibility of the form to unlock them  otherwise the image won't be GCd at all. You can use `isLocked()` to determine if the encoded image takes up the full amount of RAM. Notice that unlocked images might perform very poorly as they'll thrash the GC so tread lightly with this...

I would suggest using `FileEncodedImageAsync` for data so files can be completely removed from RAM and using it for videos too (using a thumbnail. I suggest placing the video itself only when playback starts.

The difference from `EncodedImage` is this: Even when it is GCd the `EncodedImage` keeps the "encoded" part (PNG, JPEG data). `FileEncodedImageAsync` has the data in `FileSystem` and as such the cache can be managed as files. Furthermore, the image only takes up the name of the image file in RAM assuming it isn't locked.

Comment: Could you give me some further explanation, please? Maybe I didn't understand. If I use an EncodedImage in a Form, when the image is no longer displayed because I change Form (but leaving a reference to the EncodedImage in question, in this case keeping in memory a variable with the InfiniteContainer that contains the EncodedImage), isn't the EncodedImage automatically removed from RAM until it is displayed again? Is my assumption not valid for EncodedImages but only for FileEncodedImageAsync? Also, I don't know what equivalent exists to FileEncodedImageAsync for videos.

Comment: I applied your suggestion to replace all MediaPlayers with a Label with the video preview when the video is paused: the advantage in terms of lightness seems remarkable and has solved a few problems for me. This, by the way, is a valid workaround for the problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/66144759/1277576, much better than the solution I proposed.

Comment: I added some clarifying comments. I recall writing a lot about image locking but I can't find it

Comment: First impression is that the use of FileEncodedImageAsync + image.unlock() solved my app crashes. I'll do more testing during development, but this seems like the way to go. I've noticed that InfiniteContainer scrolling slows down a lot, for one or two seconds, after scrolling a lot of content: that's perhaps the moment that the GC comes in to save from an otherwise unavoidable crash. Maybe with InfiniteContainer the use of unlock is almost a must?

Comment: This is possibly because of unlock. When you unlock and need to show an image again there's an overhead. You should also lock images back when they're in the visible zone to prevent the GC from constantly collecting them.